# How can I put alphabetically a double dimensional table?

Tags: java, arrays, alphabetical

I have a double dimensional table which on his first line has letters and below every letter there are numbers. I want to put the first line alphabetically but for every letter that change it's place I want the numbers below to move together.

For example I have this table:

```
C O R T I N A
1 1 0 0 3 4 0
4 3 3 1 2 1 3
2 1 2 1 2 2 0
0 2 3 0 2 0 4
2 3 3 4 0 4 3
2
```

and the result must be:

```
A C I N O R T
0 1 3 4 1 0 0
3 4 2 1 3 3 1
0 2 2 2 1 2 1
4 0 2 0 2 3 0
3 2 0 4 3 3 4
  2
```

I have make a try here is my code but it doesn't work. In comments is the whole code I thought I did it but it's not working. Then I tried to change just the first line and I still failed. Can someone help me?

```
                for (int i=0; i<table2.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<table2[0].length; j++) {
                    if (i==0 && ((int)table2[i][i]>(int)table2[i][j])) {
                        char d = table2[i][j];
                        table2[i][j]=table2[i][i];
                        table2[i][i]=(char)d;
//                          char [] help = new char [table2[j].length];
//                          for (int k=0; k<help.length; k++) {
//                              help[k]=table2[i+k][j];
//                              //System.out.print(help[k]);
//                          }
//
//                          for (int u=0; u<table2.length; u++) {
//                              for (int p=0; p<table2[0].length; p++) {
//                                  if (u==0 && (int)table2[u][u]>(int)table2[u][p]) {
//                                      table2[u][p] = table2[u][u];
//
//                                      for (int k=0; k<help.length; k++) {
//                                          table2[u][u] = help[k];
//                                      }
//                                  }
//                              }
//                          }

                    }



                    System.out.print((char)table2[i][j] + " ");
                    if (j==userKeyWord.length()-1)
                        System.out.println();
                }
            }
```

I forgot to mention the userKeyWord at the end is the word the user gives for the numbers to print below. (ofc it's just a part of the code)

Comment: Just to be certain, the `C` column has one extra number, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I did this by first sorting the indices of the first row based on the letter value.  Then I used those indices to rearrange the other rows to reflect the same position.  To cater to the lone value at the end I added dummy values of -1 to fill the unused array locations.  This makes the matrix more uniform and easier to work with.

```
int[][] mat = { { 'C', 'O', 'R', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'A' },
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0 },
        { 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3 },
        { 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0 },
        { 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 4 },
        { 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3 },
        { 2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 } };
```

Get the first row and sort the indices based on that.

```
int[] first = mat[0];

int[] indices = IntStream.range(0, first.length).boxed()
        .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(mat[0][a],
                mat[0][b]))
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Now use those indices to build a new matrix

```
for (int row = 0; row < mat.length; row++) {
    int[] temp = mat[row];
    mat[row] = Arrays.stream(indices).map(i -> temp[i])
            .toArray();
}
```

And then print it

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat[0].length; i++) {
    System.out.printf(" %c ", mat[0][i]);
}
System.out.println();

for (int row = 1; row < mat.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < mat[row].length; col++) {
        int v = mat[row][col];
        System.out.printf("%2s ", v < 0 ? "" : v);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints

```
 A  C  I  N  O  R  T 
 0  1  3  4  1  0  0 
 3  4  2  1  3  3  1 
 0  2  2  2  1  2  1 
 4  0  2  0  2  3  0 
 3  2  0  4  3  3  4 
    2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure why your code isn't working, but I approached it a little bit differently. Here is what I did.

```
private static final char[][] unsortedArray = {{'C', 'O', 'R', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'A'},
                                                {1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0},
                                                {4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3},
                                                {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0},
                                                {0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 4},
                                                {2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3}};

//Object to hold original index and key
private static class IndexTuple {
    protected char key;
    protected int unsortedIndex;

    public IndexTuple(char key, int unsortedIndex) {
        this.key = key;
        this.unsortedIndex = unsortedIndex;
    }
}

//Comparator to let collections sort for you
private static class TupleComparator implements Comparator<IndexTuple> {

    @Override
    public int compare(IndexTuple o1, IndexTuple o2) {
        return o1.key - o2.key;
    }
}

public static char[][] sortTable(char[][] unsortedTable) {
    //Create new array to copy result to
    char[][] sortedTable = new char[unsortedTable.length][unsortedTable[0].length];

    //Copy result to List of custom objects
    ArrayList<IndexTuple> tupleList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < unsortedTable[0].length; i++) {
        tupleList.add(new IndexTuple(unsortedTable[0][i], i));
    }

    //sort list
    tupleList.sort(new TupleComparator());

    //Using original unsorted index and new sorted index set all the values in correct order
    for (int i = 0; i < unsortedTable.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tupleList.size(); j++) {
            sortedTable[i][j] = unsortedTable[i][tupleList.get(j).unsortedIndex];
        }

    }
    return sortedTable;
}
```